# ASP.NET/CSS - using an image for a HyperLink control that I need swapped on hover over

Tags: asp.net, css

i have a HyperLink on my site that is displaying an image instead of text. what i would like is for it to swap to another image on mouse-over using css. so far, i've come up with this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlHome" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/home.gif"   
        NavigateUrl="~/Default.asp" CssClass="homeHover" />
```

my css:

```
.homeHover {  }
.homeHover:visited { background: url( ../images/home.gif ) no-repeat; }
.homeHover:Hover { background: url(../images/home_hover.gif) no-repeat; }
```

well, that does nothing. i don't know css well enough to figure this out. help please. also, i've been asked not to use javascript. i got it working using javascript but i need it to work using css. (or i suppose if i could get this to work programmatically would be okay too but... not sure about that. ) thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a.homeHover:visited { background: url( ../images/home.gif ) no-repeat; }
a.homeHover:hover { background: url(../images/home_hover.gif) no-repeat; }
```

The `:<state>` selector in CSS is what is known as a [pseudoclass](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors).  Pseudoclasses are special selectors that can match an element based on things like behaviours or relative positions.

Comment: thanks womp, you're 2 for 2 today. you helped me with my other question about the javascript i was pulling from my local resx file. it worked, but im at work right now and after i got it working they said not to use javascript. anyway, this css works too. my hyperlink control renders an <a> to the browser so i needed to add that to my css, i guess that's what it was. thanks again.